# How to disable "E768 swap file exists warning"

Tags: swap-file

I get this annoying message when I write file (using write). How can I disable it?

```
E768: Swap file exists: c:\users\ekarni\.vim\swap\template.py.swp (:silent! overrides)
```

Since I did silent! automatically I didn't see that it didn't write anything! since it was opened in another buffer.

Comment: Never use ":silent!" when writing a file. Also, never suppress/disable this warning. It's there for a reason.

Comment: I know what the reason. I still want to write. Had it not been there, it would have saved me like 30 minutes of work.

Comment: You can still write if you are determined to, but what you are doing now, and what you propose doing, WILL cost you work in the future.-

Comment: Nothing bad will happen if I disable this temporarily. Just good.  This is a lack of basic feature.